# DM on discord.py bot startup

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've got this code for when my bot code begins to be run. However, I'd also like it to DM me directly with a message saying "The bot is online" whenever the code begins running. How to I do that?

**My Code:**

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    activity = discord.Game(name="DM's being sent", type=3)
    await bot.change_presence(
        activity = discord.Activity(
            type = discord.ActivityType.watching,
            name = "Pokemon Go Discord Server!"
        )
    )
    channel = bot.get_channel(MY_CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send("Bot ready.")
    print("Ready.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(
        activity = discord.Activity(
            type = discord.ActivityType.watching,
            name = "Pokemon Go Discord Server!"
        )
    )

    member = await bot.fetch_user(MY_ID)
    await member.send("The bot is online")

    print("Ready.")
```

Where `MY_ID` is your discord ID (and integer value). Also note that for this to work you'll have to allow server DMs and the bot has to be in the same server as you are.

Comment: I'm still getting the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: @JackThorn sorry, I changed it to `await bot.fetch_user(MY_ID)`. Please try it now.